# C# wcf Client is unable to finish the security negotiation within the configured timeout in clickOnce Deployed Applications

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, timeout, clickonce

I have an network deployed forms desktop application (clickonce) which connects to an WCF service.

On most machines it works well but there are a few machines on which I get this error:

> Client is unable to finish the security negotiation within the
>   configured timeout (00:00:09.9377020). The current negotiation leg is
>   1 (00:00:09.9065530).

When I reset InternetExplorer (Settings->InternetSettings->Advanced->Reset), then this error doesn't appear any more and the application works well, so it's no timeout problem at all. (Applications are started over the InternetExplorer via link)

I think, that there is something stuck on AssemblyCache and that's why Windows can't provide credentials for the service.

I don't use certificates for the connection, and remember this phenomenon only appears on 10 out of 150 machines but the reset workaround is not acceptable over the time.

In some cases the clickonce application didn't even start.

What happens in Windows when starting an ClickOnce app?

Do you know why a reset helps, that the Client can provide credentials?

Comment: Are you trying to communicate over WCF on startup or are you waiting for the application to load completely before trying?

Comment: I connect to the WCF in Form_Load event bevore the GUI is shown. And I can't simulate the scenario on my developer pc....

Comment: I have seen this before (but can't explain exactly why).  Can you push the WCF call to after the form is loaded or on a button click?  Something is not initializing all the way before you make the call

Comment: There is no call on start, just the connections is not establlished. I can try init after the form is load, but why it should change something if the same application works well on other machines? Sadly, i don't have a machine wih this error so i cant test if somthing is gonna change...